# my question was put on hold apparently without too much of a thinking

Tags: support

[Building a computer science lab](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/5871/building-a-computer-science-lab)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, it looks like cold war to me. The question was initially put on hold because it was "too broad". I was just asking about the minimal hardware requirements for a workstation: the box itself, display, keyboard and mouse. I narrowed it to "the box" only. Now the answer of the moderator is "it qualifies as a technical support question".

Comment: I am not sure why the same moderator who marked my initial question "on-hold" edited this question as well and removed "Thank you". @ArtOfCode: you had no reason to do this.

Comment: [On the contrary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed).

Comment: it was a "Thank you".  It was not a tagline. It was not a signature. I am asking for the review of another moderator if this is possible. Thank you.

Comment: You're blowing this quite a long way out of proportion. "Thank you" is a salutation, which is discouraged by network policy, which are edited out when they're seen, all over the network. I'll call another mod if you like, but is it really worth it over such a tiny matter?

Comment: Yes please, if I'm not asking for too much. I am not here to discuss salutation policies I'm just asking for help. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need another moderator to tell you exactly the same thing as ArtOfCode♦ has already told you. They will all know the [hardwarerecs.se] policy as well as each other and it is clear to everyone that your question is still *too broad*.

Comment: I have followed all the rules. My question is not too broad. I gave the requirements and asked for help identifying the hardware that I can use while keeping it within a budget. I just defined a starting point for everyone to understand where am I at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a few different complaints. I'll try to hit them all:

#### Thank you is removed

"Thank you", and other salutations, tag lines, and signatures [don't belong in posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles) This type of thing has been [discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable) many [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed). I see you are most active on Stack Overflow...[this has been discussed there too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it).

No abusive moderation action was taken to remove these two words. The moderator was the person who happened to see it first and edited it according to network guidelines.

#### The closed question

The question closed initially as "too broad". This was the correct course of action. There are three separate questions. On top of that, you wanted recommendations for a combination of parts. The possible answers to "combinations" are huge.

We have, as a community, decided that each component needs it's own question. This allows the user and other users to more easily compare products. A combination answer is very difficult to compare, especially for new users. For example, compare three different machines that have 3 different CPUs, 3 different amounts of RAM, 3 different hard drives and 3 different video cards, but all have roughly the same price. The combinations of low end CPU but high hard drive space or high end CPU but small amount of RAM or any other combination are very hard to compare, if you don't know what you are looking at.

After your edit, the question became (and notice that it's still multiple questions):

> will raspberry pi 3 suffice for the requirements I mentioned above?

If I answer "Yes", then we are done here and I haven't made a recommendation. Instead, I've helped you determine if your machine has the specifications to run some software. That's technical support. If, however, I answer "No", I run into your follow up questions...

> I definitely don't want to go with normal workstation (heat, noise, etc). should I look for more? Beaglebone Black?

Should you look for more? Probably. I don't know. I'm guessing you want to complete this task. In which case the answer is "Yes, keep looking." If not, though, I suppose we are done. In either case, again this isn't a recommendation.

#### How do we fix this question?

Focus on your two products, and ask for the recommendation. You throw your alternative out as literally the last two words of the question and don't mention any thing else about it.

Beagleboard Black. Well, now we have two things to compare - Raspberry Pi vs a Beagleboard. We can build a question out of this. You've provided two possible solutions an your goals.

You are looking for a recommendation between the BeagleBoard and the RPi to meet this criteria:

- Hard budget limit of $2000 for 30 work stations (will need to include monitors/display and user input in this budget).
- Usage will only be programming in Codeblocks and will need an XSession. Configuration will be up to you.
- Devices must support a network connection (do you need wired, wireless or does it not matter?)

The next question you ask should be about the monitors. Keyboard and mice are cheap. You don't need anything fancy. For monitors, you will have a budget of $2000 minus either (30 * $36 (for the Pis) or 30 * 55 (for the Beagleboards) + taxes. Unfortunately, you're going to be disappointed that you can't get 30 monitors for roughly $1000.

Comment: I don't know hardware. That's why I'm here. If I would know how to ask the right question, I would probably have the right answer by  myself. Can I just thank you for your detailed answer and get out of here? I need to find a  hardware forum with lower entrance barriers for newcomers.

Comment: I don't know where to go elsewhere. I edited my question again, please review.

Comment: @sysfault try techsupport.reddit.com, they are more welcoming for people without much knowledge about hardware. This forum is more specifically dedicated to finding and seeking out niche products.

Answer (score 4):

You flagged your question for reopening once you'd edited it; I responded to that flag by commenting, and I also left a custom response to the flag. Look at your [flag history](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/4582) to see that.

With that said, I think it's a little overkill to call this the Cold War because I put your question on hold and left a comment to explain why I couldn't reopen it. All things in proportion, eh?

Your *first* revision:

> - what displays, keyboards and mice should I consider?
> - will raspberry pi 2 suffice for the requirements I mentioned above? I definitely don't want to go with normal workstation (heat, noise, etc). should I look for more? Beaglebone Black?
> - the budget is goddam low. To be explicit, I can personally go as up as $2k for the workstations and try to squeeze what's left needed from donations.

You asked 3 different questions, which is too much to deal with in one question. That's why I initially closed it, as too broad.

The question after your edit:

> will raspberry pi 3 suffice for the requirements I mentioned above? I definitely don't want to go with normal workstation (heat, noise, etc). should I look for more? Beaglebone Black?

What's happening now is that your question is giving us your idea for a system, and asking us to review a central component for its sufficiency. That's not something this site covers; it's somewhere in the sticky territory between a build review and technical support, neither of which are in-scope here.

For your question to be reopened, you should edit it so that it gives us your requirements for the workstation, and asks us to recommend *any* component that will satisfy your requirements. If you're on a budget, you can specify that and the answers will only recommend components within that budget. If you have any other unusual needs, just specify them.

Comment: A workstation without a display,  a keyboard and a mouse? Ok, fine. Just  "the box". What do you want me to do, remove the "raspberry pi 3" from my question? I am asking for another moderator to review my question.

Comment: Ugh. Again, @sysfault, another moderator will very likely tell you exactly what I just told you. It's like when you were young and your mother told you that you couldn't have a sweet - going to your father wouldn't help. Likewise, you can't just keep asking other moderators until one of them makes a favourable judgement towards you. Again, I'll ask another mod to have a look, but I wouldn't expect much out of it. On another note, if you want to ask about multiple components, nothing's stopping you asking multiple questions - just make sure they all meet the site's criteria.

Comment: I am not looking for a favorable answer. It is my right to believe that you are wrong and to ask for another opinion. That's all. Thank you.

Comment: I have followed all the rules. My question is not too broad. I gave the requirements and asked for help identifying the hardware that I can use while keeping it within a budget. I just defined a starting point for everyone to understand where am I at. And I do believe you are overreacting. I did everything (probably almost) right and much better than any other questions accepted. Can't you just admit this and reopen the question. I'm loosing precious time here and any advise from hardware masters would help me a lot. Just leave it be.

Comment: @sysfault "Can't you just admit this" - no, because it's not true. Your opinion is very much subjective - everyone thinks they've done everything perfectly. I'm not going to make an exception for you because you *think* your question is okay; either it complies with the standards we've set out, or it doesn't - and in this case, it doesn't. If you're under a time limit, you should have posted earlier to avoid this being a problem.

Comment: ok. I will just drop it. Just a quick advise, next time you will be thinking of doing a "son-parent"-type-of joke, think again. Mine died before I was able to ask for a candy. Good luck moderating your community.

Comment: @sysfault That wasn't intended as a joke in any way - it was an analogy to aid understanding. If it offended or upset you, I apologise - that wasn't my intention.

Comment: No offense. That was low coming from me too. Thank you for your support, sorry for saying thank you.

Comment: "I did everything (probably almost) right"   which translates to, did everything probably a little bit wrong :P